# Having trouble getting page-specific CSS to work on only the one designated page in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, include, stylesheet

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want to create page-specific CSS, so I created this file

```
app/assets/stylesheets/profile.css.scss
```

and then in my “app/views/users/edit.html.erb” page, I added this at the top

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "profile" %>
```

This works for this page, the problem is that this style is getting included in other pages even where I didn’t specify this stylesheet designation.  How do I get the stylesheet to only appear on the one page?

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

Remove `*= require_tree .` from application.css.scss. This line includes all the css file in all the pages

To include the controller specific stylesheet include this tag in each view
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`

If you have css that you want to include across all pages you can include
`*= require_tree ./common_dir` in application.css.scss and create the common_dir under assets/stylesheets

Comment: Yeah but that breaks other stuff.  For instance, I have a file, "app/assets/stylesheets/users.scss" that I want included on (and only on) my /users/ pages, and now it is not included.